# How to limit pending changes displayed with Team Explorer Everywhere in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

With intellij for instance, only the pending changes for the currently open project show up under changes. In eclipse when I add version control to a project it shows changes for everything in my TFS workspace. Is there a way to automatically limit the pending changes displayed to just the relevant project?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit TFS to only one project, if i remember correctly i think that you can unload projects in Visual Studio so that you can only version the projects that you want (I am sure that you must have the same functionality in Eclipse).